# Tabs in HTML mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm a tab person. Unless I'm working on a project that is already using spaces, I use tabs. I mostly do php and html work. I've  got tabs in php working well. But I can't figure out how to have html mode use tabs instead of two spaces.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(setq c-default-style "python")
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4
              tab-width 4
              indent-tabs-mode t)
```

What can I set so that html mode will use tabs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (setq sgml-basic-offset 4)
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

This works because when `indent-tabs-mode` is `t`, Emacs' default indentation logic replaces spaces with tabs whenever it can while still preserving the proper column offset for indentation. So for example if your code is supposed to be offset by four characters per indentation level (i.e. `sgml-basic-offset` is `4`, as above), your code should be indented two levels deep, and there are four columns per indentation level, then Emacs calculates that if it indents with two tabs and zero spaces, that will result in the proper column offset.

This also means, however, that the above won't work quite right if you've messed with your `tab-width`. For example if you set it to `8` and are indenting one level deep, Emacs calculates that even if it inserts just a single tab, the visual column offset (8) will be bigger than the desired offset (4). So it'll insert four spaces instead. Try setting `sgml-basic-offset` to the same thing as your `tab-width`.

Comment: Could I be doing something wrong? That code has no effect for me. Running  Emacs 22.3.1 btw.

Comment: Are you using the html-mode that is shipped with emacs or a third party one?

Comment: Just the default html-mode that is shipped with emacs.

Comment: In case any one is interested, change the 4 to 2 and the t to nil in the last two lines to create the opposite effect (only use two spaces always). HTML mode by default uses a mix of tab and space (why?).

Comment: in case this doesn't work for anyone: try making sure that your `tab-width` variable is the same as your `sgml-basic-offset`.

Answer (score 2):

actually, indent-tabs-mode should probably be t by default.

Try M-i, just for a lark. That should insert a tab character. It's not a GREAT Solution, but it might work in a pinch.

ALSO, how did you test for space vs tab? moving across it? or deleting it? you might have 'backward-delete-char-untabify' rearing it's head.

Comment: Yup, I had already tried killing and reopening the buffer and restarting emacs.